# Open a java12 jar file while 8 is still installed

Tags: java, java-8, executable-jar, java-12

Is it possible to create a executable jar file coded in java12 while java8 is still installed?
We use java8 in university but privatly im coding in 12 and so i need to find a way to run a private coded program through a jar file (created with artifacts through intellij) but still keep the java8 installment for university.

i tried this command

```
start javaw -jar jogurtLaunch.jar
```

and i tried rightclick and 'open with' and using the java12 exe (both java.exe and javaw.exe), but nothing happens except for the windows cmd prompt popping up for a few milliseconds in case of the exe and a jvm error ('Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again') popping up in case of the command.

Also i'd prefer a solution that is usable on all computers and not just for java12 development pcs.
Is there a way or do i have to code it in java8?

Comment: What is the result when you use the absolute path to the `java`/`javaw` file and start it from the `cmd`?

Comment: it can't find the name '-jar' if i remove the '-jar' from the command it starts the cmd and closes it instantly again

Comment: Use `"C:\path\to\jdk12\bin\javaw.exe" -jar jogurtLaunch.jar` to run the jar file using Java 12. Create a Windows Shortcut with that command, if you want to be able to click an icon to start the program.

Comment: as i already said that doesn't work. it only opens the console for a brief moment and then closes it again